# How to avoid case sensitive feature?

Tags: c#, winforms, string

```
string a = "sea";  
string b = "SEA"
if (a == b)...
```

How could I say that the two strings are the same, regardless of character casing ?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use string.compare:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx

```
if (string.Compare(a, b, true) == 0)
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (0 == String.Compare(a, b, true))...
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx

Comment: Will this actually work? String.compare will return 0 if the strings are equal. So in this case you would enter the if, if the strings are `not` equal... ...or did I read something wrong?

Comment: The return value of `string.Compare` is an `int`, which cannot be used with the `!` operator.-

Comment: Hm, really? Guess I'm too used to languages where integers have a specific boolean representation.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper -> That bugged me for a second, but i was too lazy to really think about +1

Answer (score 2):

use [String.Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/c64xh8f9.aspx) and use the correct StringComparison-Value:

```
if(a.Equals(b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
   ...//strings are equal
}
```

@OP: Please follow the guidelines of [whathaveyoutried.com](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) and read the docs... ...this way you would bwe able to answer things like that for yourself and you'll end up learn much more about the language and technique... :)